# Sequelize.js model.schema with include

Tags: sequelize.js

I have created a model called Person which stores records in separated tables, using .schema(tenant.name,{schemaDelimiter: '_'}).
Then, to get the relevants records, I use the following statement:

```
Person.schema(tenant.name).findAll({where: ...});
```

This works fine !

Now I add another model called EventCase and the following association:

```
Person.hasMany(EventCase,{as: 'events', foreignKey: 'entity_id', constraints: false, scope: {entity_type: 'IND'}});
```

And I want to use finders with include options.
Basically, my code is:

```
Person.schema(tenant.name).findAll({where: ...}, include: ['events']);
```

But I get an error (SequelizeDatabaseError","parent":{"code":"ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE","errno":1146,"sqlState":"42S02","sqlMessage":"Table 'data_eur1.events' doesn't exist"), because the way Sequalize generates the query does not prefix the name of the events table with the schema. I was expecting Sequelize to generate something like 'data_eur1.<%tenant.name%>_events'...

I am probably using sequelize the wrong way but I can't find anything relevant in the docs nor on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I have probably a workaround:

```
Person.schema(tenant.name).findAll({where: ...}, include: [{
as:'events', model: EventCase.schema(tenant.name)]);
```

This seems to work. But then, I don't really leverage the added value of the association.